# How to write the proper getElementBy on this Path "ID#wpbody-content>div.wrap>a" and click the <a href> using applescript and javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, applescript

I want to click the "a" href while not opening the tab to click I will just use tab number "tab 4".
I tried so many ways but find no success.

I think I'm not using the right getElementBy.

Here is my code

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell tab 2 of window 1 do JavaScript "document.getElementByClassName('wrap').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href.click;"
    end tell
end tell
```

And here my the HTML

```
div> class="wrap"
    h1> class="wp-heading-inline"
    a> href="http://versloidejos.lt/wp-admin/post-new.php" class="page-title-action"
    hr> class="wp-header-end"
    div>   div>
    div>   div>
    div>   div>
    div>   div>
    form>  form>
div>
```

I want to click "a href"

Comment: _"I think I'm not using the right getElementBy"._.  Where are you using `getElementBy.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell tab 2 of window 1 do JavaScript "document.querySelector('.wrap a').click();"
    end tell
end tell
```

You are not using the JavaScript Methods correctly to click on the link. Please check the above code. Hopefully, it will work for you.